# Working in Git Branch, and then deciding a need a new branch, some files already committed

Tags: git, git-branch

I know that if I'm working away in a branch I can create a new branch and all my commits will go to the new one.  But what if I'm working along, I've made some commits, still working, and then realize a need a new branch, including the commits I've already made (but not pushed to origin).  Is there a way I can get everything into a new branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, do the following:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

This creates a new branch from the current HEAD. Then:

```
git stash
```

This stores the current changes away for the moment. Then:

```
git checkout former_branch
```

Go back to the former branch, and:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This rewinds one commit off the end of `former_branch` (use whatever you like to point to the commit you want to go back to, maybe `origin/master` or something). Finally:

```
git checkout new_branch
git stash pop
```

and carry on working.

Comment: Good, but too much, just git checkout -b newbranch is enough :)

Comment: @Tim: That doesn't rewind the commits off the previous branch, though. I suppose the OP didn't specifically ask for that, but that's one way to do that if needed.

Comment: Yea, I don't want the commits on the previous branch.  I'll give this a shot today.